# Is it possible to subtract a Vector2

Tags: c#, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to slightly change the velocity of a ball as it collides with objects, depending on the direction it is already travelling in, in a 2D game in Unity.

To find the direction in which the ball is travelling, I have been using

```
public Vector2 ballDirection;
public Vector2 lastPosition; 

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D boing)
{
    ballDirection = transform.position - lastPosition;
    lastPosition = transform.position;
}
```

This however throws up an error reading

`Error  CS0034  Operator '-' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'`

The collision between the ball and any object prints as UnityEngine.Vector3

Is it indeed possible to subtract a Vector2 or would I be able to change the collision type to Vector2 somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can simply cast the `Vector3` variable to `Vector2` (z is discarded)

```
((Vector2)transform.position) - lastPosition;
```

or the `Vector2` variable to `Vector3` (z is set to zero):

```
transform.position - ((Vector3)lastPosition);
```

Could you please check whether it works for you?

Comment: The first piece of code worked perfectly. Thank you for this, I've been trying everything and wracking my mind for an answer. It seams so obvious now that transform.position starts as a Vector3. I was just presuming that setting ballDirection as a Vector2 would mean any transform command would be a Vector2 also.